# Convert list of strings to columns with custom rules pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have list of string within my dataframe columns:

```
data = [{'column A': '3 item X; 4 item Y; item E of size 7', 'column B': 'item I of size 10; item X has 5 specificities; characteristic W'},
        {'column A': '13 item X; item F of size 0; 9 item Y', 'column B': 'item J of size 11; item Y has 8 specificities'}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[image: df]

I want to extract numerical information from strings that contains integers, for each row.
For instance, I need to create a new column named `Size item E` that takes the value `7` for the first row  of `df` in column A, since the list contains `item E of size 7`.
If the value in the list of strings does not contain number, I just want to encode them as 1 or 0 if it is present in the original list.

Here is a summary of my desired output:

[image: df2]

This is what I have coded so far, applying only 1 rule:

```
import pandas
import re

def hasNumbers(inputString):
    return any(char.isdigit() for char in inputString)

def transform(df):

    columns = ['column A', 'column B']

    for col in columns:
        temp = df[col].apply(lambda x : str(x).split(';'))
        tokens = set([l for j in temp for l in j])
        for token in tokens:
            try:
                integer = int(re.search(r'\d+', token).group())
            except:
                pass
            if token[0].isdigit():
                df['Nb ' + token.replace('{} '.format(integer), '')] = integer
            # if ...:
                # ...other rules
            elif hasNumbers(token) == False:
                df[token] = df[col].apply(lambda x : 1 if token in str(x)  else 0)
        df = df.drop(col, axis=1)

    return df

df3 = transform(df)
```

Which is returning me the following dataframe:

[image: df3]

As you can see, I cannot apply my feature extraction by row, it updates the whole pandas series. Is there any to update new column values for each row step by step?

Comment: I recommend to reduce the complexity of your problem and try again to figure this out step by step. It seems you already have a good grip on how to approach this problem

Comment: @MarcelZoll It is not very complex as you can refer my solution to get the idea to solve in simple and easy steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't go for complex functions pandas has great string manipulation functions.
Check this code to get the desired output.

```
data = [{'column A': '3 item X; 4 item Y; item E of size 7', 'column B': 'item I of size 10; item X has 5 specificities; characteristic W'},
        {'column A': '13 item X; item F of size 0; 9 item Y', 'column B': 'item J of size 11; item Y has 8 specificities'}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#joining 2 columns with ';'
df['All Columns joined'] = df[['column A','column B']].apply(lambda x: ';'.join(x), axis=1)

#creating empty dataframe
df_new = pd.DataFrame([])

#Desired output logic using string extract function
df_new['Nb item X'] = df['All Columns joined'].str.extract(r'([0-9]+) item X',expand = False)
df_new['Nb item Y'] = df['All Columns joined'].str.extract(r'([0-9]+) item Y',expand = False)
df_new['Nb specificities item X'] = df['All Columns joined'].str.extract(r'item X has ([0-9]+) specificities',expand = False)
df_new['Nb specificities item Y'] = df['All Columns joined'].str.extract(r'item Y has ([0-9]+) specificities',expand = False)
df_new['Size item E'] = df['All Columns joined'].str.extract(r'item E of size ([0-9]+)',expand = False)
df_new['Size item F'] = df['All Columns joined'].str.extract(r'item F of size ([0-9]+)',expand = False)
df_new['Size item I'] = df['All Columns joined'].str.extract(r'item I of size ([0-9]+)',expand = False)
df_new['Size item J'] = df['All Columns joined'].str.extract(r'item J of size ([0-9]+)',expand = False)
df_new['characteristic W'] = df['All Columns joined'].str.extract(r'(characteristic W)',expand = False).notnull().astype(int)

df_new

    Nb item X   Nb item Y   Nb specificities item X Nb specificities item Y Size item E Size item F Size item I Size item J characteristic W
0           3           4                         5                     NaN           7         NaN          10         NaN                1
1          13           9                       NaN                       8         NaN           0         NaN          11                0
```

Ouput of the df_new dataframe.
[image]

Comment: @MarcelZoll Thanks to both of you, I finally succeed by mixing both code snippets to get perfect automatic extraction!